# Amazon detects scrapy instantly. How to prevent captcha?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape one web page from amazon with the help of Scrapy 2.4.1 over shell. Without any prior scraping amazon instantly askes for captcha entries.

I am setting another user agent as only prevention but have never before scraped the page:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"
```

Get one page:

```
>>> fetch('https://www.amazon.de/Eastpak-Provider-Rucksack-Noir-Black/dp/B0815FZ3C6/')
>>> view(response)
```

Results in a captcha question.

I also tried it with headers:

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
>>> req = Request("https://www.amazon.de/Eastpak-Provider-Rucksack-Noir-Black/dp/B0815FZ3C6/", headers=headers)
>>> fetch(req)
```

This also results in a captcha question, while the main page can be scraped in this case.

How does amazon detect that this is a bot and how to prevent that?

Comment: are you using any proxy? how many requests for ```.../dp/``` URL(s) you have performed?
Your example works on my side, so looks like you have performed a lot of requests for the same (or similar) url

Comment: I have only done 2 or 3, it was instantly like this. No proxy as I did only fetch the URL via shell manually.